# Iptables not forwarding. Input instead

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, routing

I have set up iptables on my ubuntu headless server:

```
iptables -S

-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.1.3.90/32 -i eth0 -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT: "
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i ppp0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.1.3.90/32 -i eth0 -j LOG --log-prefix "FORWARD: "
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -S -t nat

-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -s 10.1.3.90/32 -j LOG --log-prefix "ROUTE: "
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11108 -j DNAT --to-destination 169.254.1.2:11108
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 11108 -j DNAT --to-destination 169.254.1.2:11108
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5555 -j DNAT --to-destination 169.254.1.2:5555
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 169.254.2.2
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 169.254.1.2/32 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 169.254.2.2/32 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

When i send UDP packet to port 11108 it should be routed to ppp0 169.254.1.2:11108 and FORWARD rule should apply. 
instead a INPUT rule is applied and packet is not routed.

this is the log from kernel. there is no FORWARD:

```
Jun 20 10:58:51 ubuntu kernel: [  337.871043] INPUT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:1c:42:02:04:dd:00:1c:42:d7:b0:24:08:00 SRC=10.1.3.90 DST=10.1.3.117 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=22127 PROTO=UDP SPT=11108 DPT=11108 LEN=32 
Jun 20 10:58:53 ubuntu kernel: [  339.865420] INPUT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:1c:42:02:04:dd:00:1c:42:d7:b0:24:08:00 SRC=10.1.3.90 DST=10.1.3.117 LEN=68 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=22484 PROTO=UDP SPT=11108 DPT=11108 LEN=48 
Jun 20 10:58:55 ubuntu kernel: [  341.864446] INPUT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:1c:42:02:04:dd:00:1c:42:d7:b0:24:08:00 SRC=10.1.3.90 DST=10.1.3.117 LEN=68 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=22818 PROTO=UDP SPT=11108 DPT=11108 LEN=48 
Jun 20 10:58:57 ubuntu kernel: [  343.707469] ROUTE: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:1c:42:d7:b0:24:08:00 SRC=10.1.3.90 DST=10.1.3.255 LEN=229 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=23133 PROTO=UDP SPT=138 DPT=138 LEN=209 
Jun 20 10:58:57 ubuntu kernel: [  343.863994] INPUT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:1c:42:02:04:dd:00:1c:42:d7:b0:24:08:00 SRC=10.1.3.90 DST=10.1.3.117 LEN=68 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=23266 PROTO=UDP SPT=11108 DPT=11108 LEN=48 
Jun 20 10:58:59 ubuntu kernel: [  345.877465] INPUT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:1c:42:02:04:dd:00:1c:42:d7:b0:24:08:00 SRC=10.1.3.90 DST=10.1.3.117 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=23684 PROTO=UDP SPT=11108 DPT=11108 LEN=32 
Jun 20 10:58:59 ubuntu kernel: [  345.879215] INPUT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:1c:42:02:04:dd:00:1c:42:d7:b0:24:08:00 SRC=10.1.3.90 DST=10.1.3.117 LEN=68 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=23707 PROTO=UDP SPT=11108 DPT=11108 LEN=48 
Jun 20 10:59:00 ubuntu kernel: [  346.010347] ROUTE: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:1c:42:d7:b0:24:08:00 SRC=10.1.3.90 DST=10.1.3.255 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=23798 PROTO=UDP SPT=137 DPT=137 LEN=58 
Jun 20 10:59:00 ubuntu kernel: [  346.759893] ROUTE: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:1c:42:d7:b0:24:08:00 SRC=10.1.3.90 DST=10.1.3.255 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=23811 PROTO=UDP SPT=137 DPT=137 LEN=58 
Jun 20 10:59:01 ubuntu kernel: [  347.509887] ROUTE: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:1c:42:d7:b0:24:08:00 SRC=10.1.3.90 DST=10.1.3.255 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=23944 PROTO=UDP SPT=137 DPT=137 LEN=58 
Jun 20 10:59:01 ubuntu kernel: [  347.878185] INPUT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:1c:42:02:04:dd:00:1c:42:d7:b0:24:08:00 SRC=10.1.3.90 DST=10.1.3.117 LEN=68 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=24086 PROTO=UDP SPT=11108 DPT=11108 LEN=48 
Jun 20 10:59:01 ubuntu kernel: [  347.881900] INPUT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:1c:42:02:04:dd:00:1c:42:d7:b0:24:08:00 SRC=10.1.3.90 DST=10.1.3.117 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=24109 PROTO=UDP SPT=11108 DPT=11108 LEN=32
```

Comment: Is the 169.254.1.2 address assigned to an interface on the same machine?  IIRC, the packet won't hit the FORWARD chain in that case since it's handled/routed internally, assuming you've enabled IP forwarding.

Comment: no the 169.254.1.2 is on the other side of P2P connection ppp0. it is android connected via adb. The link is ok. i can ping it from ubuntu and back

Comment: Your FORWARD chain is set to drop as the default, but you aren't allowing forwarding from eth0 to ppp0 (-i eth0 -o ppp0) in your rules.  Can you also confirm that IP forwarding is enabled in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding?

Comment: i've tried the FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp0 but it did not help. It shoulb be covered in general -i eth0 rule. And yes ip_forward is enabled in sysctl

Comment: I've found out that the port i'm trying to redirect is open at the time of redirection. there could be ongoing communication on this port but i need to redirect it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your ruleset to the bare minimum and start testing from there.  There's some redundant rules which may be conflicting.  I would start with:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 11108 -j DNAT --to-destination 169.254.1.2:11108
```

I would also use `watch` to see what chains/rules the packets are hitting

```
watch -n1 iptables -vnL
watch -n1 iptables -vnl -t nat
```

The APIPA address isn't necessarily the best thing to use for the client, but that shouldn't affect receiving packets.

Comment: Sorry didn't help. I've traced the error to that if i use the port on local machine before redirection is applied then the rule is not forwarded. If i don't use the port before it works correctly